# Kanji or kana for いってきます?

Tags: kanji, set-phrases, kana

Should I use kanji or kana for the first and second verbs in いってきます? When each verb is used individually there's usually kanji if I recall correctly, but I'm wondering if it's changed for being used in a stock phrase, and if so whether the first, second or both verbs use kana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it as 行ってきます, with きます in Hiragana, probably because the きます([来]{く}る) is a subsidiary verb (補助動詞) here.

Comment: 「いってきます」と書くときもあると思います。でも、「行って来ます」は、あまり書かない気がします。